# How to create android app that will tell me how much battery is being used by each installed app

Tags: android, performance

How to create android app that will tell me how much **battery** is being used by each installed app.Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

There is no an API to retrieve this. The calculation done for the battery stats UI in the Settings app is a complicated approximation (taking into account CPU stepping etc. to some extent) and is very much an approximation. It is not accurate enough for Google to make it available via an API.

In short, there is no way to do this, as mentioned by a Google employee [here](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/android-developers/128pee7q49/how-to-get-battery-usage-from-cpu-usage-in-android).